# Can monads replace macros when writing a redis json driver?

Tags: macros, clojure, monads

In this [blog entry by Jim Duey](http://www.intensivesystems.net/tutorials/why_monads.html) - he provides a list of reasons that you'd want to use monads. One his reasons is this:

*So what are some clues that a monadic solution is possible? It seems to me that anytime you're copying and pasting code to define a new function that's similar to an existing one, there might be a monad lurking.*

This is actually quite similar to the justification for using a Clojure style macro.

In this [presentation by Aaron Bedra](https://github.com/abedra/yow-2012/blob/master/doc/Yow!%202012.pdf?raw=true) - he talks about a use case for Macros when writing a redis driver to generate json. On slide 66 - he shows an example of this.

```
￼(defmacro defcommand
  [name params]
  (let [p (parameters params)]
    `(defn ~name ~params
```

My question is - can Monads be used to solve this problem of duplicate code when generating json for redis calls instead of a macro?

**Assumptions**

- I understand it is more idiomatic to choose a macro over a monad in Clojure. For the purpose of this question I'm choosing to ignore what is idiomatic and just look at what is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monads and Macros operate at different levels of abstraction.

I think of macros as "code monkeys": anytime I find myself writing a lot of boilerplate, I take a moment and think whether macros can help.

Monads on the other hand are very powerful abstractions generally used in order to isolate and compose side effects in a purely functional setting. (I'm not an expert on Monads so take this with a grain of salt).

The bottom line is that I think they are solving fundamentally different problems.

If we take the example you provided, writing a Redis driver, any function accessing the network is a candidate for an abstraction through monads - in this case, both the IO and Maybe  (or Either) monads. But not because of repetition, but rather because your functions have side effects.

Now this is where Monads in clojure can get harder than it's worth: If you want to compose both monads, you need to use [monad transformers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers). Obviously this is not enforced by clojure since it's a dynamic language so one can argue debugging composed monadic code in a dynamic language can be very hard. A static type system such as Haskell's would be of great help here.

So while a redis driver can definitely be written in a monadic style, I believe the point Aaron is making in the presentation is avoiding repetition, and for that, I believe macros are a better fit in Clojure.

I hope this is helpful.

**EDIT**:

I should also node that monads in Clojure would be hardly useful without the Haskell inspired *do* notation which is essentially made possible by macros, providing further proof that macros are at a different level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

> anytime you're copying and pasting code to define a new function
>   that's similar to an existing one

I would create a higher order function to get rid of copy paste, as simple as that.

Now, Macro or Monad or even a simple higher order function solves a single purpose but at different conceptual levels. The purpose is to "abstract away a common pattern in a system".
The different conceptual levels at which you can see a pattern appearing in a system are:

- Same chunk of code - Use function / higher order function
- Same chunk of code but that require some sort of "compile time" preprocessing to make it abstract - Macro
- Pattern of "A value inside a box with some context" and it fits with the monad laws - Monads. (Maybe, IO, List - all these are API patterns where we see a value inside a box with some context)

I know it sounds very "abstract", but once you practice enough thinking about how to abstract general patterns in your system, you will eventually get the intuition about which tool to use for which pattern.